# Floats inside absolute positioned div

Tags: css

Is it possible to have multiple floats inside a absolute positioned div without specifying the width of the absolute container?

See image:
[image]

**Ninja edit:**
Your code with absolute and floats works perfectly, but just not in my case. I tried to simplify the problem, but obviously something else is wrong. I will come back to you as soon as i figure out why. Sorry.

**Edit 2:**
Right, this is the reason for my problem.

**HTML**

```
<div id="anotherContainer">
    Outercontainer
    <div class="main">
        <div class="left">Left</div>
        <div class="right">Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#anotherContainer {
    position: relative;
    outline: 4px solid red;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.main{
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    position: absolute;
}

.left{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
    padding: 20px;
}

.right{
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    padding: 20px;
}​
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rP76V/)

My mistake, I assumed the container #anotherContainer would not have any effect on this.

Comment: I am able to do it in firefox: The code was:

<div style="height: 200px; border: 1px solid;">
<div style="float:left; width: 200px; height:200px; border:2px solid"></div>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid; float: right;"></div>
</div>

Comment: Yes it is. Have you tried it and are having problems or are you just asking? http://jsfiddle.net/43U5z/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove position relative on `#anotherContainer` problem will be solved.
check jsfiddle working link

http://jsfiddle.net/rP76V/3/

Comment: Thanks. This, with some javascript for positioning on the x-axis worked.

Answer (score 3):

Floats are not contributing for width/height of parent container, however you can use

```
display:inline-block
```

Or for more complicated situations display as: table, table-cell, table-row, etc..

See more at: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Review (example)

```
<div style="position:absolute;border:solid 1px red;">
  <div style="display:inline-block">A</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block">B</div>
</div>​
```

You can also not specify width of inner div and let browser choose by using

```
<div style="position:absolute;border:solid 1px red; display:table-row">
  <div style="display:table-cell">A</div>
  <div style="display:table-cell">B</div>
</div>​
```

With this, both divs will have same height.

If you want inner divs to have same width then:

```
<div style="position:absolute;border:solid 1px red; display:table-row">
  <div style="display:table-cell;width:50%">A</div>
  <div style="display:table-cell;width:50%">Blejf lkwejf lwekfjlkw ejfjwelf jlkwe jflkw elfk wlek flkwe flk wjelfkj lwke jflkw elkfjlwej lfkwjelkf lkweflk</div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Hi! inline-block on the absolute container, or the floats? Thanks for the tip about table-*.

Comment: instead of float, remove the floating so that the size accounts to the parent

Comment: neu-rah: But then, how can I place them next to each other, like in image above?

Comment: if no width/height specified (inner divs) they will size by the content, and inline means they will be next to each other as long as they can fit on total width, if you have large content then specify width for each of the inner

Answer (score 1):

Check the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/c9ShQ/

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main{
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    position: absolute;
}

.left{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
    padding: 20px;
}

.right{
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    padding: 20px;
}
```