# Div appearing in front of div within a different container/section

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website at the moment where I have four sections with various divs inside them, but content from the third is overlapping content from the second, like the height for the second is not automatically adjusting to its content.

With there being a lot of code for this its difficult for me to demonstrate the whole issue in jsfiddle, so a live example of the issue can be seen at www.nickcookweb.co.uk/test, where the 'Blog' title section overlaps the services grid from the previous section.

(PS. I'm aware there are also many other issues...Still working on them and will most likely post more questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're floating all your `.service` divs and never clearing them.

You can do the following to resolve it...

```
<div id="servicesGrid">

   <div class="service"></div>
   <div class="service"></div>
   <!-- etc... -->

   <div style="clear: both;"></div> <!-- Solution -->
</div>
```

While a div will expand to fit its content by default, a `float` changes this behavior. Without a clear, it will pretend that those floated elements aren't even there. We can address and fix this by doing a `clear: both;` after our last floated element.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the position of the servicesGrid to static and that seemed to do the trick:

```
#servicesGrid {
    position: static;
}
```

Edit: Here is someone with a very similar issue: [Floats inside absolute positioned div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848106/floats-inside-absolute-positioned-div)

Comment: Please note that the answer you've included in your edit is from 2012. I'd also argue that it's completely incorrect but that's neither here nor there.

Comment: The issue is not the floats clearing described in your post. The issue is that you have an relatively positioned div (the blog) sitting on top of an absolutely positioned div (services). I added your suggested solution to the DOM and it did not fix the problem.

Comment: I just tried and you are correct, fixing the floats does not fix the issue on its own. I apologize for being so confident in my own mistake. That being said, if you set the div to `position: static;` or `position: relative;` and hover over it in Inspect Element view, you'll notice it has a height of 0. For this reason I'd still highly suggest clearing the floated elements, otherwise the divs below will start experiencing the same issues.

Comment: No problem. That does make sense. I'm having trouble understanding why OP positioned the divs this way in the first place.